# Android : How to use same AlarmManager in loop?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, alarm

I write bellow method for alarm.

```
 public void alarm(int time){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Alarm.class);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0 , intent, 0);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+time*1000, pi);
}
```

This method working perfectly. But the problem when I call the method more than one time. Like,

```
alarm(10);
alarm(50);
```

This time it only invoke `alarm(10);` But don't invoke `alarm(50);`

Anyone please help why it show this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `PendingIntent` has the same properties both times you call your method. When you call `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` the second time it will return the `PendingIntent` that was already created the first time.

If you want the alarm to trigger twice you need to do something like this:

```
public void alarm(int time, int requestCode){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Alarm.class);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), requestCode , intent, 0);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+time*1000, pi);
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
alarm(10, 0);
alarm(50, 1);
```

Comment: Hello Sander, thank you so much for your response, was a really useful code.
You saved my life, I was in troubles in my job for a issue with that but you are my hero. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You are giving the same ID (0)
You need to use different unique id. use different pending intent id like this. you can use millisecond as id.

```
public void alarm(int time, int requestCode){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Alarm.class);
    Long timeToMilliSeconds = timeToMilliSeconds(hour, minute);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), timeToMilliSeconds , intent, 0);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+time*1000, pi);
}
```

Comment: if it works than mark it's as an answer and give up vote

Comment: Already a person given this answer. That's why I can't give you right answer. But it's also helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the same ID `0` (the second parameter in `PendingIntent::getBroadcast`) to more than one`PendingIntent`. This is your mistake.

Depending on the `FLAG` you set, the behavior may vary.

Consider either using a different ID for each `PE` or one of the [standard flags](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT).

Also see:

- [Wrong pending intent is being triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985900/geofencing-wrong-pending-intent-is-being-triggered/48989253#48989253)
- [How does android compare pending intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520951/how-does-android-compare-pending-intents?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Adding flags to PendingIntent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792843/adding-flags-to-pendingintent)

Answer (score 0):

```
// context variable contains your `Context`
AlarmManager mgrAlarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
   // Loop counter `i` is used as a `requestCode`
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, intent, 0);
   // Single alarms in 1, 2, ..., 10 minutes (in `i` minutes)
   mgrAlarm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60000 * i, 
                pendingIntent); 

   intentArray.add(pendingIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call it like this

```
alarm(10, 0);
alarm(50, 1);
```

For more than one Pendingintent it needs different id so in the caller method pass
different id.